# Compare two dependent variables of proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, independence

I have a group of 20 subjects that is measured twice (pre- and post-treatment). Each time the measurements are proportions. Values range between 10% and 40%. Both variables are not normally distributed. I would like to know if there is a difference pre- to post-treatment.

1. How can I compare those two dependent variables of proportions? Can I use a Wilcoxon rank test? Or is there a more appropriate test?
2. Assuming, that my data would be normal, could I use a dependent-sample t-test?